# Ruby on rails: Multiple controllers in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I'm creating a questionnaire application, allowing users to create a questionnaire.

A questionnaire is made up of two different controllers:

- Questions
- Content (Allowing headings in between questions to break them up)

I then have a 'Questionnaire_Items' controller, which is what pulls questions and content together. This contains question_id or content_id and an order value.

So I need my questionnaire_item view to pull in either question data, or content data (depending on whether question_id or content_id is present).

What's the best way to do this?
Is there a better way to achieve what i'm trying to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a separated frontend and backend, or is it a single "monolithic" application? (Is the whole thing ruby on rails, or do you have an `EmberJS`/`AngularJS`/`ReactJS`/... front-end, consuming JSON from the API?)

Comment: Just using ruby on rails.

Comment: Have you tried `render “some_view”, layout: false`?

Comment: No, I guess i'm just looking for the best and most efficient way to pull from two different controllers into one view. How would I specify what to render? Because it would be different depending on whether the entry is question or content.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you might be thinking about this a bit wrong. See here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#what-does-a-controller-do-questionmark; a controller receives a request and decides on the response, so your controller determines the view to render, the view does not decide what controller to 'pull' from.  Also, are Question and Content not models?

The simplest way I can think of to do what you want is to build a questionnaire item in your controller, then render your view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that, but I used the wrong terminology.

You are correct I need to build a questionnaire item in my controller. This item needs to contain 'questions' and 'content' and I then want to order it based on the 'order' in the questionnaire_item table. It's this bit that i'm struggling with.

Comment: I see. Have a look at this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/7-design-patterns-to-refactor-mvc-components-in-rails/
I think the service objects section might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want  is make DB queries. Try something like this on your controller:

As example

```
Question.find_by(id: idName)
```

and example for content

```
Content.find_by(id: anotherIdName)
```

You must understand Question and Content as instance objects from a class and then, the method find_by from activeRecord allows you to search on DB.